# How to use a struct in a COM object

Tags: python, com

I'm working on a python script which calls a COM object to operate a camera. And when scripting, I meet an issue, "How to use the *struct* defined in COM object".

For example, from *OLE/COM Object Viewer*, one of the struct is,

```
typedef [uuid(XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX), version(1.0), helpstring("image unit")]
struct tagUDT_ImageUnit {
    unsigned char* pData;
    long data_len;
} UDT_ImageUnit;
```

And one of the API uses this struct,

```
HRESULT GetImage(
            [in] UDT_ImageUnit* pImageUnit,
            [in] UDT_ImageUnit* pWhite,
            [out, retval] long* ret);
```

If using Python, how can I call this struct? Thanks!

Comment: Does Python rely on Automation (`IDispatch`) to access COM? IDispatch does not support structs even if COM in general does.

Comment: Yes. But we can use **win32com.client.Record** to create a COM_Record to access a struct. 
For example,

    objCOM = win32com.client.Dispatch(ProgID)
    objRecord = win32com.client.Record(Struct, objCOM)

However, if there is an indicator existed, there are two error reported,
    - when using UUID of the struct, it reports, ValueError("The structure '%s' is not defined in module '%s'" & (name, package))
    - when using name of the struct, it reports, "com_error: (-2147319783, 'Old format or invalid type library.', None, None)"